# elastic scattering of neutrons

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

what is the meaning of elastic scattering of neutrons with a light nucleus. During the process, it is converted from fast neutron to a thermal one. how?

Comment: Quantitatively, what is the difference between a thermal and a fast neutron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reaction between a neutron and a nucleus is governed by the strong force, which is difficult to calculate exactly

However "elastic" scattering means, *by definition*, that whatever happens *during* the interaction the particles that come out of it are of the same kind and internal state as the one that went in. This means that in order to preserve energy and momentum, the velocities before and after the interaction will necessarily follow the same rules as in plain old Newtonian (or, for high speeds, special-relativistic) mechanics.

What comes out of that analysis is that *in the center-of-mass frame*, and an elastic collision between two particles, the *speed* of each particle *cannot change*, though they may get new *directions*.

If a fast neutron hits a stationary heavy nucleus, the center-of-mass is dominated by the nucleus, so the center-of-mass system does not move much with respect to the lab frame. Therefore the neutron will more or less *preserve its speed* in the lab frame -- it bounces right off the nucleus.

However, if it hits a stationary *light* nucleus, then the center of mass moves with an appreciable fraction of the neutron's velocity. When the neutron comes out of the collision in a random direction (relative to the CoM system), it is likely that its new speed *in the lab frame* is significantly lower than it was before. (Draw a diagram here!)

As long as the neutron is fast compared to the thermal motion of the nuclei it scatters on, it tends to shed a fixed percentage of its speed in each collision, to pretty quickly it will slow down until it is *not* fast anymore. That is, it has become "thermal", meaning in (mechanical) thermodynamic equilibrium with the nuclei.